# AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: report, line 7

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When i try to give `report_name` in report tag it throws below error:
`AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: report, line 7`

***.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

   <report id="action_report_followup"
   model="account_followup.followup"
   report_name="PPPPPPPPPPpppp" //Here is the problem
   string="Follow-up Report"
   report_type="qweb-pdf"
   name="payment_followup.report_followup"
   file="payment_followup.report_followup"
   menu="True"/>

</odoo>
```

If i remove attribute `report_name` it will work fine, and use value of `string` as report name. I need to give other name. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: We suppose the attribute is just 'name' and not 'report_name'. Can you please check that?

Comment: That is the answer, so make it one ;-)

Comment: Thank you @CZoellner, we will change it to as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute that you are trying to use here, `"report_name"`, is the culprit. There is no attribute such as `"report_name"`. Use the attribute `"name"` instead.

See the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

   <report id="action_report_followup"
   model="account_followup.followup"
   string="Follow-up Report"
   report_type="qweb-pdf"
   name="payment_followup.report_followup"
   file="payment_followup.report_followup"
   menu="True"/>

</odoo>
```

Comment: In your answer there is two `name` attributes. It gives me ans error `XMLSyntaxError: Attribute name redefined, line 11, column 19`. So i removed one attribute (`name="payment_followup.report_followup"`) and restarted my module. After this i tried to print report it throws another error:`ValueError: Invalid template id: u'PPPPPPPPPPpppp'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this once.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report
            string="Follow-up Report"
            id="action_report_followup"
            model="account_followup.followup"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="payment_followup.report_followup"
            file="payment_followup.report_followup"
            menu="True"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```